# Separate behavior from entity is hard to use design parttern

Tags: java

I have a problem.When I follow the MVC model,It always Separate behavior from entity,class will like `TeacherService` ,`Teacher`,`TeacherDao`.`Teacher` only have setter/getter.But it's hard to use design pattern.For Example,the teacher can send msg for every `Student`,I hope there has a MsgQueue to help the teacher do it and the teacher don't have to wait.When the task finished,I hope the MsgQueue can notify teacher and do something.So I want to use Observer Design Pattern,because separate behavior from entity,I don't konw which I should call(Teacher or TeacherService) when the MsgQueue finished the task.
Is it incorrect to separate behavior from entity?Or how should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have misunderstood the design pattern.

The MVC is about the design of the tool user interface and keeping that separate from the model.

- The Model classes are ... well ... the collection of domain objects for the application.
- The View classes are the ones that are responsible for rendering the objects in a displayable form; e.g. onto the screen
- The Controller classes are the ones that perform the actions that happen when the user clicks a button, for example.

The Model classes *could* have complex behavior if that is appropriate to the application.  It *could be* appropriate for one part of the Model to notify another part of the Model, and / or for the Model to notify the View class that the display needs to be updated.

Remember that a design pattern is really a guide or template on how to do things.  There is nothing to stop you from doing things a bit (or a lot) differently, if your application requires this.  But the most important things is to have a clear understanding of *why* you are doing things; e.g. why you are putting behavior in the Model classes, rather than somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer.The JAVAEE project I have seen always have  `XXXEntity`,`XXXService`,`XXXDao`.I think these alway be long to model,is it right?These always put the business layer of enity into service because it's easy to test and the entity won't be heavy.Is it right?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  However, the fact that you have (only) seen examples that do something one way does not imply that that is the only correct way ... or the best way in all circumstances.

Comment: Anyway,Thanks you for your answer.